# JSON + Array events in same calendar?

Tags: json, fullcalendar

Good afternoon, currently using JSON feed for my calendar which works ok. Is it possible for me to also add a few events via an array and change colour of these? I want to add bank holidays as an array and colour them green where possible?

Currently my code looks loike this, could I add array of events under the json feed?

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },

        startParam: 'start',
        endParam: 'end',
        editable: true,
        minTime: 9,
        maxTime: 21,
        allDayDefault: false,
        events : {
            url: 'json-events.php',
                        }
    });
```

Any advice appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

In document.ready() method or just before your calendar code. Create event sources like this:

```
source1 = {
    url: 'json-events.php',
    type: 'POST',
    error: function() {
        //alert('There was an error while fetching events!');
    },
    color: '#4ca64c',
    textColor: 'black'
};

source2 = {
    url: 'array-events.php',
    type: 'POST',
    error: function() {
        //alert('There was an error while fetching events!');
    },
    color: '#4caca4',
    textColor: 'black'
};
```

The in fullCalendar declaration:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    ...
    eventSources: [
    // your event source
        source1,
        source2
    ],
    ...
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Adil, sorry for delay that works a treat thank you very much, I did it slightly different, probable long winded but it works just the same.